# How do I handle some but not all http methods in compojure with Liberator?

Tags: clojure, compojure, liberator

I'm using liberator with compojure, and wanted to send multiple methods (but not all methods) to the save resource.  Rather than repeating myself, I'd like to have something that defines multiple handlers at once.

An example:

```
(defroutes abc 
  (GET "/x" [] my-func)
  (HEAD "/x" [] my-func)
  (OPTIONS "/x" [] my-func))
```

Should be closer to:

```
(defroutes abc
  (GET-HEAD-OPTIONS "/x" [] my-func))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several false starts, I realized that the compojure.core/context macro can be used for this purpose.  I defined the following macro:

```
(defmacro read-only "Generate a route that matches HEAD, GET, or OPTIONS"
  [path args & body]
  `(context "" []
        (GET ~path ~args ~@body)
        (HEAD ~path ~args ~@body)
        (OPTIONS ~path ~args ~@body)))
```

Which will let you do:

```
(read-only "/x" [] my-func)
```

And seems to do what I need.

Comment: This worked better for my particular use case, but James' code and comments show a good way to handle it if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the [tutorial](http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/tutorial/all-together.html) the idiomatic way is to use the `ANY` key on the route and then define the `:allowed-methods [:get :head :options]` on your resource. You will need to implement the `:handle-ok` and `:handle-options`

```
(defroute collection-example
    (ANY ["/collection/:id" #".*"] [id] (entry-resource id))
    (ANY "/collection" [] list-resource))


(defresource list-resource
  :available-media-types ["application/json"]
  :allowed-methods [:get :post]
  :known-content-type? #(check-content-type % ["application/json"])
  :malformed? #(parse-json % ::data)
  :handle-ok #(map (fn [id] (str (build-entry-url (get % :request) id)))
                   (keys @entries)))
```

Comment: I saw that, but that seems to preclude handling the other methods in another resource, since they would be routed to the resource, the kicked back by the allowed methods filter.  I also didn't want most decision functions (like malformed?) in the resource to have to check which HTTP method is being used.  I'll try to update my question with a more complete example.

Comment: I see your point, in such case your own answer seems good enough. Another alternative could be to use inheritance from a common base resource if you have further needs.

Comment: I'm looking forward to the common resource configuration I saw on the mailing list.  I think that would do the trick also.  Thanks!

Comment: A good source of inspiration to define base resources https://github.com/paddleguru/liberator-friend/blob/master/src/liberator_friend/resources.clj and also a nice apportation, thanks to https://github.com/sritchie